# Blaze realtime database storage minimum price

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The pricing page isn't clear about the realtime database storage pricing for the blaze plan. It just says $5/GB. How does that work?

If I only use 0.1GB do I get charged $0.50?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're on the Blaze plan, you get charged on the exact bandwidth you used. If you use a fraction of a GB, you'll be charged for only that fraction.